# How can i redirect to an external page from fastapi's exception handler

Tags: python, cors, fastapi, saml

I'm writing a web-app that has to support Single-Sign-On through Saml. The back-end is made with FastAPI and the front end is made in react. Nginx is used to proxy requests to the backend. I have an endpoint for logins that returns a redirect request to an identity provider. When accessing the endpoint directly through the browser everything works as expected and the user is redirected to an external login page.

I want to be able to use a similar redirect when a user who isn't authorized tries to access the page. My attempt at this consists of returning a redirect response, when a http exception is raised, to my login endpoint which should then redirect to the external login page. Doing this prompts a 404 response from the idp.

[image]

The login endpoint is defined like this in FastAPI:

```
@app.get("/saml/login")
async def sso(request: Request):
    req = await prepare_from_fastapi_request(request)
    auth = Saml2_Auth_patched(req, saml_settings)
    callback_url = auth.login(return_to="https://website.com/")
    response = RedirectResponse(url=callback_url)
    return response
```

And the exception handler like this:

```
@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def unauthorized_handler(request: Request, exc):
    response = RedirectResponse(url="/api/saml/login")
    return response
```

Comment: Generally you'd make FastAPI return a 401 Unauthorized response, and then you'd have logic in your React application (through Axios for example) that changes the current route for a 401 response to the login endpoint; that way the logic about what to do when authentication is required is up to your application. If you want to handle redirects, you'll need to intercept any 307/302/301 status codes and then change the active URL in your application.

Answer (score -1):

This looks more like a front-end issue since as you are saying everything works as expected when you access the endpoint in the browser.

I think the issue here is that the library you are using to make API requests from your front end application does not follow redirect. For example axios does not do that out of the box. You can see the conversation here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1350

In the same conversation they mention another dependency you can use to address this issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects

Comment: This is speculation and an incorrect one.  A CORS issue is not with axios.

Comment: The second request has a CORS error, but the first one returned a redirect status code